# Barplot without alphabetizing x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphs

I'm inputting a .csv file and then plotting a barplot based on the colnames but when I go plot the order the names are being alphabetized rather than get the order that is in the .csv file. How to I prevent that from happening?

```
p2 = ggplot(data=clusters_per_sample, aes(x=sample, y=Perc, fill=cluster)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = getPalette(22))+
  theme_minimal() + labs(y="percentage of total # cells in the sample") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, face = "bold")) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, color="black"))
```

I tried this to get rid of the alphabetizing but my bars are very thin when doing so:

```
p2 = ggplot(data=clusters_per_sample_2, aes(x=sample, y=Perc, fill=cluster)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity")+ scale_x_discrete(limits=clusters_per_sample_2$sample) +
heme_minimal() + labs(y="percentage of total # cells in the sample") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, face = "bold")) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12, color="black"))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ggplot2 uses factors on the underlying data frame. To have the data plotted in a custom order, apply a custom ordered factor on the underlying dataset.

For example, if `clusters_per_sample$sample` is your custom-ordered vector, do this:

```
clusters_per_sample$sample <- factor(clusters_per_sample$sample, levels = unique(clusters_per_sample$sample), ordered = TRUE)
```

Now when you plot `sample` as an aesthetic, ggplot has a factor component to work with already, so it won't try and make a new one (this new factor would have been in alphabetical order, which we circumvent with the `ordered=TRUE` parameter in our custom factor).

Comment: Where do I add that line in my code?

Comment: Add it in before passing the object to `ggplot()`. This step is part of preparing your data for plotting.